# In which cases is ObjectSid-Attribute missing for persons in ActiveDirectory?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

While trying to get users by ObjectSid, I discover that some person-Object does not have this Attribute. I'm wondering if this is a common case or an error in our directory.
The reason because I want this to know is that I'm writing a program to query LDAP by SID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within AD's schema, the [Person class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683895%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) does not define an `Object-SID` attribute. The [User class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683980%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) does define `Object-SID` and it is mandatory.

It may be worth noting that neither [Top](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683975%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (from which Person is sub-classed) or [Organizational-Person](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683883%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (from which User is sub-classed) define `Object-SID`.  `Object-SID` is defined on the User class via its Auxiliary Class, [Security Principal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683947%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).